# NSMenuItem not receiving keyEquivalentModifierMask control with WKWebView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview, appkit

`NSApplication.mainMenu` with 2 `NSMenuItem` and the following `keyEquivalent`:

- ⌃ ⇥ *(Control Tab)*

```swift
keyEquivalent = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSTabCharacter)]
keyEquivalentModifierMask = NSEvent.ModifierFlags.control
```

- ⌃ ⇧ ⇥ *(Control Shift Tab)*

```swift
keyEquivalent = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSTabCharacter)]
keyEquivalentModifierMask = [NSEvent.ModifierFlags.control, NSEvent.ModifierFlags.shift]
```

They work as expected with any `NSView` except with a `WKWebView` and any other `keyEquivalent` combination work.

Apparently the menu item is not receiving the event, as clicking directly on the item works as expected too, even if the key equivalent didn't.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `WKWebView` intercepts `⌃ ⇥` and `⌃ ⇧ ⇥` without passing them down the `NSReponder` chain, like it does with some other commands.

These commands use the selectors from `NSWindow`:

- `⌃ ⇥`: [selectNextKeyView(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419715-selectnextkeyview)
- `⌃ ⇧ ⇥`: [selectPreviousKeyView(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419110-selectpreviouskeyview)

The solution is to subclass `WKWebView` and implement those selectors.

Example:

```swift
final class WebView: WKWebView {
    @objc func selectNextKeyView(_ sender: Any?) {
        // implement Control Tab
    }
    
    @objc func selectPreviousKeyView(_ sender: Any?) {
        // implement Control Shift Tab
    }
}
```